# SharePoint Pop up after every reboot of system.

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, popup

how do I please disable this notification? SharePoint 2013 is these tools are not needed. It pops up every time server is rebooted. Thank you.
[image: Notification]

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a server configuration, you have to turn off the User Account Control. 
User Account Control (UAC) can help prevent unauthorized changes to your computer.
To turn it off: 
 -Start
 -Control Panel. 
 -Search for uac, and then click Change User Account Control settings.
 -Move the slider to the Never notify.

Turn it off at your own risk. Maybe it is better just to set a lower level, not the lowest.
Source:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Please do not post link only answers! Add some details to your post to make it less dependent on the link

Comment: Done! Added details

Comment: I'd like to note that turning off UAC is **definitely** not recommended.

Comment: Hello, I do not want to disable UAC of course. Id just like to stop this pop-up window appearing.

Comment: Can I delete the MSECache entry ?

Comment: @SkyDive You mean the folder C:\Program Files\MSECache? It is an installation folder for Office products. Sorry but,why do you want to delete it?

Comment: Just the entry which is used by the sharepoint pop-up

Comment: @SkyDive It seems that it try to run the "PreRequisite SharePoint". Didyouinstall all the preRequisites?

Answer (score 0):

Turing UAC from control panel is not always a good option but you can always change it to 25% from default 75% .